# Babel writes utf-16 file; how can I make it write uft-8?

Tags: babeljs, utf-16

When I run `babel --plugins transform-react-jsx like_button.jsx > like_button.js` the resulting `like_button.js` is utf-16 encoded (and `like_button.jsx` has some 8 bit encoding, probably utf-8).

How can I make bable write `like_button.js` utf-8 encoded?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what it is you're seeing, because Babel definitely doesn't write files in UTF-16. It might write out certain characters using escape sequences instead of literals, but that's not related to the character encoding.

Comment: I uploaded the file to [link](https://rai4u.de/like_button.js), but I am not sure whether it got converted during upload. Here [link](https://rai4u.de/screenshot_like_button.js.png) is a screenshot of a hex view of the file.

Comment: Huh! Does your terminal maybe have an encoding set in settings? Does it happen if you do `-f like_button.js` instead of `> like_button.js`, I'd guess not. Maybe the `>` redirection is re-encoding the utf8 into utf16?

Comment: Changing the terminal (from Windows powershell to Windows cmd) solved it! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Babel's output is definitely UTF-8. Since you are seeing UTF-16 in your file, and the file is being written by your terminal, it seems most likely that your terminal is re-encoding the data before writing it to a file.

The easiest option for you would be to change from

```
-babel --plugins transform-react-jsx like_button.jsx > like_button.js
+babel --plugins transform-react-jsx like_button.jsx --out-file like_button.js
```

so that Babel itself is responsible for writing the output to the file, which removes the terminal from the equation.

If you don't want to do that, you'll need to look into your terminal options to see if there is an explicit encoding set somewhere.